# AJAX POST submit to PHP - empty POST on arrival at PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I am submitting a POST request via AJAX to my PHP script. The browser tools `Network` tab shows the POST data has values, on arrival at my PHP script the `$_POST` value is true, `isset()` verification is valid, and there should be no problem to assign the `$_POST['input']` values to my `$variables`.

Yet, my debug bar tells me that the PHP variables like `$first_name` are infact empty. I am feeling very stupid here, what am I missing?

**AJAX**

```
$('#newUserSubmit').click(function() {
    console.log('Submit button clicked.');

    if ($('#addNewUser').valid()) {
        console.log('Form on submit is valid');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../controllers/admin_addNewUser.php',
            data: {
                action: 'add_new_user',
                user_data: $('#addNewUser').serialize()
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log('Ajax POST request successful.');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Ajax POST request failed.');
                console.error(xhr);
            }
        });

    } else {
        console.log('Form on submit is invalid');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Browser Network Tab:**

```
Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
action: add_new_user
user_data: first_name=John&last_name=Doe
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $debug_msg = 'POST check: passed<br>';

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action'] == 'add_new_user')) {
        $debug_msg .= 'ISSET check: passed<br>';

        // sanitize
        $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['first_name']);
        $ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['last_name']);

    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: first_name in <b>/path/to/script/admin_addNewUser.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: last_name in <b>/path/to/script/admin_addNewUser.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
```

Appreciate any help on this, been staring at this for too long already.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending the `data` object wrong. Sending the `Serialize` function as an object element will send it literally as a string. so the output for your data obj will be something like

```
data: {
    "action": "add_new_user",
    "user_data": "first_name=val&last_name=anotherval"
}
```

wich will be parsed as an array on the PHP side.

So you will need to replace the

```
data: {
    action: 'add_new_user',
    user_data: $('#addNewUser').serialize()
}
```

by something like:

```
data: $('#addNewUser').serialize() + '&action=add_new_user'
```

OR in PHP side you will need to parse the `user_data` query string into an array like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_data'])) {
    parse_str($_POST['user_data'], $userData);

    // then you can 
    if (isset($userData['first_name'])) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it had to be something small like this... thanks a lot, time to get some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax object, if you see the data attribute, you'll see that first_name is not sending directly. It is in the "user_data" variable.

You need to use `$_POST[user_data]` = to get the details of the form.

Also if you find any query like this in the future, just use `print_r($_POST)` to see what you are getting from the POST request.

Thank you.